# If $P$ and $Q$ are Lebesgue partitions then is $P\cap Q$ a refinement to $P$ and $Q$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My teacher said that if $P$ and $Q$ are Lebesgue partitions then $P\cap Q$ is a refinement to $P$ and $Q$.

But shouldn't $$P\cup Q$$ be the refinement to both $P$ and $Q$?

Or, are both $P\cup Q$ and $P\cap Q$ refinements to $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: A refinement of a partition is a superset of the given partition, by definition. In general, $P\cap Q$ is not a refinement of neither $P$, nor $Q$.

Comment: @GitGud ,So is $P\cap Q $ a refinement of $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: Reread my comment, I had a small typo.

Comment: @GitGud, What about $P\cup Q$?

Comment: What does the definition tell you?

Comment: @GitGud, $P\cup Q$ is a superset of $P$ and $Q$ so its a refinement to both.

Comment: $P\cap Q$ could be "short hand" for $\cup_{p\in P,q\in Q}p\cap q$.

Comment: @user3879021 Exactly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Is $P\cap Q$ a refinement with your definition?

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's changing the extremely well established definition of $\cap. If you change the meaning of standard symbols to make it fit something, then anything can be "true".

Comment: @GitGud Since what is written here is second-hand information, I am suggesting that something might have been lost in translation.  The definition that I suggested could be a reasonable interpretation of what was actually meant as it is the smallest partition that is a refinement of both $P$ and $Q$ (but, looking back, I forgot set symbols, it should read $\cup_{p\in P,q\in Q}\{p\cap q\}$).

Comment: The smallest partition that is a refinement of both $P$ and $Q$ is exactly $P\cup Q$. Your notation is still flawed, though. If $P=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Q=\{1,3\}$, what do you mean with $p\cap q$ where $p=2$ and $q=3$?

Comment: @GitGud I see the confusion now, I think of a partition of a set $X$ as a pairwise disjoint collection of subsets whose union is the whole space.  Then, my notation captures the same concept that you're describing, but when $P$ and $Q$ are collections of sets and not collections of points.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Right, I completely forgot about that meaning of *partition*. I assumed the OP meant something else because of the context. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) for the meaning being used here.